# Google Playstore beta and alpha mode got only the alpha version

Tags: android, google-play

I'm using the great service of **Google Playstore** to publish beta to my community before going live to production.

**It is working great for the beta part**, now I need to use the alpha service and beta for two different and separate group and it is not working **I got my alpha 2.0 version for the beta users**…

- V1 -> live
- V1.1 -> beta testing
- v2.0 -> alpha testing

**BETA**

- Community named "Beta testers"
- user beta@google.com + 1 external user + customerBeta@google.com*1

**ALPHA**

- Community named "Alpha tester"
- Members : alpha@google.com + customerAlpha@google.com*2

**More info**

- *1 : is also the email creator of the playstore account and owner of the community "Beta tester"
- *2 : is the owner of the community "Alpha tester"
- all theses emails are unique with google+ account + validated the community invitation.
- all testers have accepted the link of https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.xxx.xxx
- The playstore is configured with the correct community name (no inversion or whatever)

**TEST PROTOCOL AFTER ONE DAY OF TESTING**

- Reset two tablets with factory settings
- alpha tablet got unique account -> alpha@google.com
- beta tablet get unique account -> beta@google.com

But both alpha and beta got v2.0, I checked 10 times the settings. I tried with a independent email too without success I got the alpha.

I read this but I don't see any error in my configuration… "

> Please keep in mind that if a user is eligible for both alpha and beta
>   versions, they’ll receive the alpha version.

Where Is the mistake what can I check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer : **"Timing"**. I thought I waited enough after 3h to 5hours.

I checked this morning arriving at work. So it tooks about 12h to 20h to be functional without any changes.

I also confirm that it is **working with multi-user** starting with Android 4.2 on the same tablet with :
- one User account with google beta@gmail has primary google account 
- one User for alpha user with alpha@gmail.com set has primary account.

**Import** : having two google accounts with the same user and switching the account into the playstore is not working for beta and alpha testing, only the primary is working.

Comment: ["After publishing an alpha/beta APK, it may take up to 24 hours for your test link to be available to testers."](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)

Comment: Sometime it takes only 2hours… I guess, there is a kind of opaque batch running to active apps…

Comment: Yes, it was very quick for me too — about 1 hour —, I just quoted the manual, because we should only start to worry/complain after a day passed.